# WCF Web Service Reference and AspNetCore.SignalR Hub

Tags: wcf, signalr

I'm in charge of the development of a 10 years old solution composed by a WCF Web Service Reference and WPF Client. For the moment, each client asked the WS once per minute for updated data with a db row version. With the increasing number of users, I decided to use SignalR in order to reduce the I/O in the database and make the WPF Client display instantly the updated data. I can't rewrite all the client and server code <=> I want to use as many existing code as possible.

There are 3 ways to achieve my goal :

1- client => HUB => WS => HUB => client

(1 HUB project, more code changes : client has to subscribe and send the data to the HUB, no changes WS side)

2- client => WS => HUB => client

(1 HUB project, fewer code changes : WS has to return the result to the HUB and the client has just to subscribe to the HUB)

3- client => HUB/WS (merged) => client

(this my favorite, the existing WS inherit from Hub. No extra project. I can apply the concept 2 with this one)

What I tried so far following the three concepts above :

1- add a .NET Framework 4.8 (SDK-style) console project HUB. I can't achieve (totally) to add a Web Service Reference to the project because : "You have referenced a project that targets a different version of .NET Core or .NET Standard. Reuse of types in referenced assemblys has been deactivated...". If I can't reuse my types that's not a good solution. What's wrong ? WS and HUB projects are both .NET Framework 4.8. Maybe the SDK-style of the HUB project which contains two mysterious files Sdk.props and Sdk.targets is related ?

2- add a .NET Framework 4.8 (SDK-style) console project HUB. I can't achieve to communicate to the HUB from the WS because of some files failed to load during runtime. Sometimes `System.Buffers, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`...

3- incorporate the HUB into the WS by inheritance, The hub is configured then started in the WS static ctor. Same problem as idea 2 except the hub starts with RunAsync (else it blocks the WS thread)

I precise that I only achieve to communicate between client => hub and client => ws with these libraries below.

The used libraries are :

Client side :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 6.0.0.0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core 6.0.0.0

Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1
```

Server side :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2.0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.1.0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.2.0

Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1
```

In point 2, WS is considered as a client too (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client`) but is not subscribed to anything, the idea is simply to do WS=>HUB without expecting any response. The hub then dispatch the response to all subscribed client.

What is the best solution to achieve my goal ?
Can I really have one incorporated SignalR hub in a WCF service ?
Can a SignalR hub be hosted in IIS (express for dev, local for prod) ?
Why can't I communicate between WS=>HUB or HUB=>WS

Comment: Do I have to be more or less specific ?